# multiple conditions in =sum

Tags: excel, formula, conditional-statements

```
Phone number    Provider    Duration (min)
1001            Fastcom         2
1002            Fastcom         1
1004            Mobilecom       4
1008            Telecom         5
1001            Fastcom         3
1001            Fastcom         2
1003            Telecom         3
1004            Mobilecom       2
1008            Telecom         6
1002            Fastcom         1
```

I want to use one formula to get the sum of the duration of calls whose service provider is the provider for the phone number 1001. I hope this revised version is clearer than the previous one. Again, thanks to all who paid attention.

Comment: I personally find this question a bit confusing. Could you please rephrase your question to make it a bit more clear? Perhaps elaborate the example a bit further.

Comment: I don't understand how the sum for Adam results in 44.

Comment: Hi, Cutter! Essentially, I'm looking for the sum in Column D based on the condition in Column C based on the condition in Column B. Or put in another way, first i find the seasons that correspond to Adam, which are spring and fall, and then i get the sum of all the numbers that correspond to spring and fall, which gives us 44.

Comment: Hi, Jurgemaister! My apologies for the mess. I hope the edited version now is at least a little more understandable.

Comment: What happened to Adam? I hope he didn't get seasonal affective disorder.  (Just kidding.)

Comment: Adam, together with his athletic friends, disappeared tragically because of my carelessness. XD

Comment: Ah well.  Welcome to SO and I'm glad you got your answer.

Comment: Thank you Doug Glancy! How come i had't known SO all the time!!!!!!!! I hope i can improve myself so much that i can help someone else here, too)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*There are 14 rows. Column A contains numbers from 1 to 14. Column B contains Names of people(maybe repeated). Column C contains their preferred seasons (possible more than 1) and Column D contains how many days they do sports in that partucular season. I need one formula to get how many days are spent doing sports in the season(s) that is (are) preferred by Adam, which actually are Spring and Fall*

Assuming data in rows 2 to 15 try this array formula

`=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2:C15,IF(B2:B15="Adam",C2:C15),0)),D2:D15))`

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: Hey, Barry Houdini! Thanks a million!!! That is the correct formula! Thank you!!! I wanna mark it as useful but sadly it turns out i can't because of my user status.

Answer (score 1):

In one formula I'm not sure. Personally I'd have a formula in each row of column E that is `0`  or the value from D, then you can `sum(e:e)` instead.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm new here and have just known that i can't yet post images. I edited the question which contains data copied from a table. Here's a brief description of the table. There are 14 rows. Column A contains numbers from 1 to 14. Column B contains Names of people(maybe repeated). Column C contains their preferred seasons (possible more than 1) and Column D contains how many days they do sports in that partucular season. I need one formula to get how many days are spent doing sports in the season(s) that is (are) preferred by Adam, which actually are Spring and Fall.

Comment: Does the seasons actually matter? Would the data be in the table in the first place if it wasn't a preferred season with >0 number of days? In that case, am I right when I say you want to add how many days Adam is doing sport?

Comment: Yes, the seasons do matter. Adam likes Spring and Fall. Hans loves summer and winter, and so on. At the same time, Adam, Indiana, and Larry like Spring. Adam, Daniel, Indiana, and Mike likes fall. All the numbers of days in Column D, corresponding to the two seasons spring and fall, if summed up, gives 44. Maybe i should rebuild the table and make it clearer. I'm sorry for the mess and thank you for your attention.